# Add a vertical line to a line chart from the googleVis

Tags: r, linechart, googlevis

What I would like to do is add a vertical line to a line chart in R from the googleVis package.  Does anyone know if this is supported? For example, given the following simple line chart, I would like to add a vertical line at x=2. Is this even possible?

```
# Simple example. Must bring in 'googleVis' package first.  

df <- data.frame(country=c(1,2,3), val1=c(1,3,4), val2=c(23,12,32))
Line1 <- gvisLineChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2"))
plot(Line1)
```

Comment: I realized how to do it by asking the developer.  You use NAs to get a vertical reference line like this:

library(googleVis)
dat <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,1,3,4),
                  y1=c(0,3,NA,NA,NA),
                  y2=c(NA,NA,0,3,2))
plot(gvisScatterChart(dat,
                      options=list(lineWidth=2,
                                   pointSize=2))
)

Answer (score 0):

I realized how to do it by asking the developer.  You use NAs to get a vertical reference line like this:

```
library(googleVis)
dat <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,1,3,4),
              y1=c(0,3,NA,NA,NA),
              y2=c(NA,NA,0,3,2))
plot(gvisScatterChart(dat,
                  options=list(lineWidth=2,
                               pointSize=2))
)
```